# Algorithm to quickly check amount of intersection in a list of shapes

Tags: algorithm, performance

So I got a list of shapes and already have an algorithm to check if two shapes intersect. Now I'm trying to figure out an efficient algorithm to go through a list and count the number of intersections.

What I have now is simply two for loops that compare the first element of the list to everything that comes after it, then do the same for the second element and etc. That's O(n^2) isn't it? I'm not quite sure how I would go about making it more efficient as I don't think you can sort a list of shapes or use hashtables if that does anything here.

Comment: You don't tell enough about these shapes and how densely they are packed.

A possible strategy is to surround your shapes with axis-aligned bounding boxes and implement an efficient rectangle-overlap algorithm. (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00989481)

Comment: You will need these 2 for loops to check all possible intersection. What you can do to optimize is to try to discard quickly pairs of shapes that cannot overlap without having to apply the full intersection algorithm. Rectangular bounding boxes suggested by @YvesDaoust can be a very efficient way to do it

Comment: @AmoRobb: no, trying all bounding boxes in a double loop is no improvement, it keeps an O(N²) complexity. A sweepline algorithm will *not* try all pairs of boxes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, actually his algoritm takes O(N^2·M) where M is the number of operations needed to verify that 2 shapes overlap. And M is usually very significant. If you first discard using bounding boxes, of cost m, being M>>>m, complexity can be reduced almost to O(N^2) which is an improvement.

Comment: @AmoRobb:  of course, but O(N log N + K) is better (K is the number of overlaps found). So much better that the cost of computing the bounding boxes, O(NM) can become dominant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, if that is the case and N is the same order as M or greater, you are right, should be better. I don't have access to the article that you linked, so i'm not sure how the bounding boxes must be computed for that algorithm, but it sounds interesting anyway

Comment: @AmoRobb: the algorithm deals with axis-aligned rectangles. I mentioned it also for the bibliography.

Comment: Yes, I know that from the abstract, the bounding rectangles I suggested are orthogonal as well ( not the smallest fitting rectangle, obviously). I was just not sure if the ones needed for the algorithm are just the smallest axis-aligned rectangles or they have to meet any other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Split your 2D space into a "nice power of 2" number of tiles. For example, you might have 8 rows and 8 columns to get 64 tiles.

For each polygon, add a `tileFlags` field. This will be 1 bit per tile, which indicates if the polygon does/doesn't overlap with the tile (and is the reason why you want a "nice power of 2" number of tiles).

To determine a polygon's `tileFlags` field; find the vertex/vertices with the lowest y-coord (and if there's 2 or more find the left-most and right-most vertex). From the starting vertex/vertices; trace the polygon's left and right edges from one vertex to the next, as you set flags corresponding to "tiles between left and right edge" each time you reach a new left/right vertex and each time you cross a "tile top/bottom". Note that this is a minor adaption of the algorithm you'd use for software rendering ("rasterization" for drawing polygons); just with "pixel" replaced with "tile" and "color" replaced with "1-bit flag"; and you should be able to find a better description of it (maybe even with example code). It is somewhat error prone (e.g. you have to take some care when vertices are perfectly on a tile's boundary); and becomes much harder and more expensive if the polygon can be concave (better to disallow concave polygons or maybe detect them and temporarily split them into convex polygons).

Once that's done, you can do `if( (polygon1->tileFlags & polygon2->tileFlags) != 0) { /* Polygons might intersect */ } else { /* Polygons can't intersect */ }` as a preliminary intersection test to avoid a much more expensive intersection test.